# Не восстанавливается Fragment при повороте устройства

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть активити. Вот все, что оно делает:

```
fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment_container, ViewPagerFragment.newInstance(hero)).commit();
```

То есть, добавляет в контейнер фрагмент с `ViewPager`:

```
public class ViewPagerFragment extends Fragment {

private ViewPager mViewPager;
private TabLayout mTabLayout;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private Hero hero;
private int currentPage;


public static ViewPagerFragment newInstance(Hero hero) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable("hero", hero);
    ViewPagerFragment fragment = new ViewPagerFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    if (getArguments()!= null)
        hero = getArguments().getParcelable("hero");
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        currentPage = 0;
    } else {
        currentPage = savedInstanceState.getInt("Page");
    }
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_pager, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_pager_fragment);
    ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.main_view_pager);
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.main_tabs);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(new MainPagerAdapter(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), hero));
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);




    mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
            currentPage = position;
            Log.i(TAG, "onPageScrolled: "+ position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            currentPage = position;
            Log.i(TAG, "onPageSelected: "+ position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });


}



@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
     outState.putInt("Page",currentPage);
    Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState " );
  }
}
```

Но почему-то `savedINstanceState` всегда равен `null`. Остальные вопросы на эту тему на stack'e не помогли.

Comment: Если я не прав поправьте. Нужен пустой конструктор `public`

Comment: @СергейГрушин к сожалению нет, 1) у меня нету конструкторов а значит по умолчанию неявно есть пустой 2) я попробовал и не помогает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фрагменты автоматически восстанавливаются в активити при её пересоздании после поворота. Судя по всему вы каждый раз при пересоздании добавляете новый фрагмент поверх имеющегося. И в новом фрагменте, естественно, сохранённого состояния нет. Попробуйте в активити проверять наличие фрагмента и, если он уже есть, не добавлять новый. Примерно так (добавляем тег при добавлении фрагмента чтобы потом по нему искать):

```
Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("TAG");
if(fragment == null) {
    fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment_container, ViewPagerFragment.newInstance(hero), "TAG").commit();
}
```

Также стоит отметить что FragmentStatePagerAdapter автоматически сохраняет текущую выбранную страницу при повороте экрана и сам же её восстанавливает и применяет. Дополнительных действий не требуется. Во всякой случае если ViewPager находится в актвити это верно

Comment: FragmentStatePagerAdapter не сохраняет, видимо потому что находится во фрагменте, а вот проверка помогла, и информация новая, буду знать, большое спасибо